# Lambda .OrderByDescending causing timeouts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, timeout, sql-order-by, sql-function

I've executed this table valued function for quite some time without issues. It appears that out of no where I am unable to now successfully run this query in EF without a timeout.

```
context.ItemJobWhereUsed_F(invid, orgid).OrderByDescending(x => x.SCHEDULED_START_DATE).ToList();
```

I ran the generated SQL query on the SQL server and it returns results in milleseconds.

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[DISCRETE_JOB] AS [DISCRETE_JOB], 
[Project1].[CUSTOMER_NAME] AS [CUSTOMER_NAME], 
[Project1].[SCHEDULED_START_DATE] AS [SCHEDULED_START_DATE], 
[Project1].[JOB_STATUS] AS [JOB_STATUS], 
[Project1].[Qty] AS [Qty], 
[Project1].[SCHEDULED_COMPLETION_DATE] AS [SCHEDULED_COMPLETION_DATE], 
[Project1].[LINE] AS [LINE], 
[Project1].[RUN_NUMBER] AS [RUN_NUMBER]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[DISCRETE_JOB] AS [DISCRETE_JOB], 
    [Extent1].[CUSTOMER_NAME] AS [CUSTOMER_NAME], 
    [Extent1].[SCHEDULED_START_DATE] AS [SCHEDULED_START_DATE], 
    [Extent1].[JOB_STATUS] AS [JOB_STATUS], 
    [Extent1].[Qty] AS [Qty], 
    [Extent1].[SCHEDULED_COMPLETION_DATE] AS [SCHEDULED_COMPLETION_DATE], 
    [Extent1].[LINE] AS [LINE], 
    [Extent1].[RUN_NUMBER] AS [RUN_NUMBER], 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [eng].[ItemJobWhereUsed_F](@InventoryID, @OrgID) AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[SCHEDULED_START_DATE] DESC
```

I also found that if I write the lambda like this it works properly. (no timeout)

```
JobsWhereUsed = context.ItemJobWhereUsed_F(invid, orgid).ToList();
JobsWhereUsed = JobsWhereUsed.OrderByDescending(x => x.SCHEDULED_START_DATE).ToList();
```

I am lost as to where I can diagnose why this query is failing. Could someone point me in the right direction in determining the cause of this error? This is running a SQL table valued Function with EF Model First.

Also worth noting, I recently upgrade to .NET 4.5.2 from 4.5.

Comment: Have you tried running the generated query under SSMS and checking the execution plan?  There's nothing wrong with this code.  It is most likely related to your table valued function interaction.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the second case (using intermediate `ToList()`, although `AsEnumerable()` will be sufficient) is not comparable because the ordering happens in memory.

Comment: Yes I checked the SSMS execution plan an it was absolutely good. I was just reading about something called 'parameter sniffing'..

Comment: What does the SQL without the Order By look like?

Comment: @TravisPeterson have the database size grown lately? And do you have index on SCHEDULED_START_DATE?

Comment: I literally have no idea... now it is working.. I'm going to blame corporate IT and say our 'security' expert is breaking stuff.

Comment: The sort in the first code is done on the server, the sort in the second code is done on the client (memory).